# Patent WO 2008099192 A1 - thrust vectoring in general?

Tags: conflict-of-interest

How can [this](http://www.google.com.ar/patents/WO2008099192A1) patent exist?
It is such an essential function for aerial vehicles and there are hundreds of patents for aerial vehicles and propulsion mechanisms which utilise thrust vectoring, are they violating this patent?
I would like to file a patent for two-axis thrust vectoring system for fixed wing UAVs, would it conflict with this patent?

Answer (score 2):

This is not an issued patent. It is the publication of an international *application* for a patent that went nowhere. It looks like it was never even put in front of a patent office for examination.